# readonly on change in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> I want to fire an `on change` event for a `read-only` input in jquery
>   and then append some HTML code below it. So basically, whenever the
>   `read-only` input changes, `HTML` code should be appended.

Please see my code below.

```js
$(function(){


 $(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
  
   $('#holder').val($('#getter').val());
  
  });
  
  // This part
  $('#holder').on('change', function(){
  
   $('.here').append("<p>Inputted</p>");
  
  });


});
```

```css
input[readonly=""]{
  
  background: #ccc;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<br><br>

<input type="text" id="holder" readonly="">

<input type="text" id="getter">

<button>Go</button>

<br>
<br>

<div class="here"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `.trigger("change")` to `$('#holder').val($('#getter').val());` then it will work;

**Demo**

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', 'button', function() {
    $('#holder').val($('#getter').val()).trigger("change");
  });
  $('#holder').on('change', function() {
    $('.here').append("<p>Inputted</p>");
  });
});
```

```css
input[readonly=""] {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<br><br>

<input type="text" id="holder" readonly="">

<input type="text" id="getter">

<button>Go</button>

<br>
<br>

<div class="here"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

this should be what you looking for it can be done with one event only

```js
$(function(){

  $(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
  
  $('#holder').val($('#getter').val());
  
  $('.here').append("<p>Inputted</p>");
  
  });
  
});
```

```css
input[readonly=""]{
  
  background: #ccc;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<br><br>

<input type="text" id="holder" readonly="">

<input type="text" id="getter">

<button>Go</button>

<br>
<br>

<div class="here"></div>
```